# Is there a Ferromagnetic material that I can put in a microwave oven

Tags: electromagnetism

I am curios to know if there are any Ferromegnetic material or permanent magnets that I can use in a microwave.

I need to paste such a material to a plastic utensil that I will use in a microwave.

Intuition tell me that I need a material with extremely high resistivity and low'ish permeability so that it does not heat up and something like a fridge magnet strip or a Ferrite-NiZn might do the trick.

Just wanted to get some feedback here before I smoke something in my microwave.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to"crisp or brown food", the following patent  (and some others, I believe) may be relevant: https://www.google.com/patents/US6077454
The following site discusses testing of ferrites in microwave oven: http://www.eham.net/ehamforum/smf/index.php?topic=46347.0;wap2 . They suggest placing a container with water in the oven (to absorb microwave power for safety) and test for no more than a few seconds.
Please be careful. Try it at your own risk:-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. I do not want to brown food. I am thinking of a utensil attachment that snaps easily using magnets. A microwave "resistant" ferromagnetic/magnetic material will be glued on the utensil.

The utensil might need to be microwaved for 30-60 seconds and hence the question.

I am trying to figure out ferromagnetic/magnetic material attached that can be glued to the utensil.

Comment: the utensil attachment is supposed to snap to what?